# Use linq to make a projection of an anonymous class with a list

Tags: c#, linq, projection

Suppose I have these classes:

```
public MyClass
{
   public Property1 {get; set;}
   public Property2 {get; set;}
   public Property3 {get; set;}
   public Property4 {get; set;}
   public Property5 {get; set;}
   public Property6 {get; set;}
   public Property7 {get; set;}
   public Property8 {get; set;}
   public List<MySecondClass> MyList {get; set;}
}

public MySecondClass
{
   public SecondProperty1 {get; set;}
   public SecondProperty2 {get; set;}
   public SecondProperty3 {get; set;}
   public SecondProperty4 {get; set;}
   public SecondProperty5 {get; set;}
}
```

Supposing that everything is instantiated, how would I use linq to make a projection that just had `Property1` and `Property2` and a list that just had `SecondProperty4` and `SecondProperty5`?

Something like:

```
myClass.Select(x=> new { Property1 = x.Property1, 
                         Property2 = x.Property2, 
                         //Some Way To add The list here
                       }
```

NOTE: Just to clarify myClass is a `List<MyClass>` object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
myClass.Select(x=> new { Property1 = x.Property1, 
                         Property2 = x.Property2, 
                         SecondList = x.MyList.Select(i => new { i.SecondProperty4, i.SecondProperty5 }).ToList()
                       }
```

Comment: I feel dumb for not realizing that!  Thanks for the answer.